# How to do windowing, FFT and display result

Tags: matlab, window, fft

I'm trying to input a .wav file by

```
    filename = 'C:\Users\kiit\Desktop\New folder\file.wav';
    [y, Fs, nbits] = wavread(filename)
```

after that I'm calculate the length by-

```
L=length(y)
```

I've performed hamming window by-

```
w=window(@hamming,L);
```

when I perform fft by

```
F=fft(y,w)
```

It's showing warning as 
    Warning: FFT length must be a non-negative integer scalar.

```
F =

Empty matrix: 0-by-1
```

Any help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fft` command is wrong.  The second argument is the FFT length, not the window.

```
Y = fft(X,n) returns the n-point DFT. fft(X) is equivalent to fft(X, n) where n 
is the size of X in the first nonsingleton dimension. If the length of X is less 
than n, X is padded with trailing zeros to length n. If the length of X is 
greater than n, the sequence X is truncated. When X is a matrix, the length of
the columns are adjusted in the same manner.
```

To window, you apply (elementwise multiply) in the time domain (i.e. `y.*w`).

And to understand the output of `fft`:

- [Why does FFT produce complex numbers instead of real numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304532/why-does-fft-produce-complex-numbers-instead-of-real-numbers)
- [Converting Real and Imaginary FFT output to Frequency and Amplitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453714/converting-real-and-imaginary-fft-output-to-frequency-and-amplitude)

Comment: I get it but I'm having problem in your last statement  do you mean to say that I'm, doing hamming window wrong or in fft command should I use(y.w*)

Comment: Window the signal first (`y_w = y.*w;`), then do the FFT (`F = fft(y_w);`.

Comment: I did what you told me to. It's showing a star kinda formation and I don't think this is what I want.

Comment: I think you got it.  What commands are you using to display the result?

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply and I'm using plot(F)

Comment: when I use this command F=fft(y_w); it displays nothing. then to see waveform I plot it using plot(F). I do know about output produced by fft What I'm unaware is the waveform. how should it look like?? or am I doing it right and thank you so much

Comment: Did you see the links I added?  `fft` does not display anything.  The Fourier transform is a frequency space, with frequency on the x axis with magnitude and phase (obtained by abs and angle) on the y axis.  Please read the links.  I'm pretty sure that more than answers your question.  I hope you manage to learn the meaning of the FFT.